# How to properly write seed method in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am learning ASP.NET and I am using EF Core in my project. I would like to seed some test data when I'm running my migrations. Here's my `AppDbContext` class and my model classes:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Studio> Studios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        var converter = new EnumToNumberConverter<Genre, byte>();

        builder.Entity<Game>().Property(item => item.Genre).HasConversion(converter);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0.0, 1000.0)]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Studio Studio { get; set; }
}

public class Studio
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Game> Games { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Budget { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

As you could notice there's a little bit complicated relation between Game and Studio entities. Not only game has a studio which created the game, but also a studio has a list of games developed by them.

If I had to write `OnModelCreating` method, I would firstly create some test people and then use them to fill `Employees` field in `Studio` class. The problem occurs when I have to create games. Studio does not exist yet and if I wanted to create studios first, games are a missing element.

Do I have to manually create some games, ignoring the Studio reference, then instantiate studios, and then manually link object together, or is there any better solution? Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's because people only read the title, but everybody jumped to how to seed in Entity Framework, period. Next, some came up with `AddOrUpdate` which doesn't exist in EF core.

Seeding in EF core has changed dramatically compared to EF6. In EF6's `Seed` method it was possible to save an object graph, i.e. objects containing references and collections. However, the `AddOrUpdate` method had a couple of issues (I won't spell them out here) that made its behavior very hard to follow or even get right if you weren't aware of them.

As an (over)reaction to that, the EF team decided to no longer let EF determine whether an entity should be added or updated. Seeding should either add an entity if it's non-existing, or do nothing otherwise. Never update. These considerations lead to a greatly (over)simplified seeding mechanism in EF core:

- Entities should be identified by their hard-coded primary keys 
  . If necessary, they're inserted with `IDENTITY INSERT ON` (in Sql Server).
- Foreign keys should also be hard coded.
- Navigation properties can't be populated. If they are, EF will throw an exception like

  > InvalidOperationException: The seed entity for entity type 'Studio' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Games' set. To seed relationships you need to add the related entity seed to 'Game' and specify the foreign key values {'StudioId'}.

That means that you have to add `StudioId` to `Game`. And `StudioId` and `GenreId` to `Person`. Independent associations (a `Studio` reference without `StudioId`) aren't supported. (I think this is a far-reaching architectural decision).

Doing that, your seeding code, simplified a bit, could look like:

```cs
var games = new[]
{
    new Game{ Id = 1, Name = "Game1", StudioId = 1 },
    new Game{ Id = 2, Name = "Game2", StudioId = 1 },
};
var studio = new Studio
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Studio1",
};

modelBuilder.Entity<Studio>().HasData(studio);
modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().HasData(games);
```

The circular reference `Studio` ⟷ `Game` doesn't matter here because it represents only one foreign key.

However, circular references over two foreign keys are impossible. Suppose `Studio` had a `Director` property of type `Person` referred to by `DirectorId` and the director is also an employee:

```cs
var director = new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Director1", StudioId = 1 }; // Employee of Studio1

var studio = new Studio
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Studio1",
    DirectorId = 1 // Director is "Director1"
};
```

Now there's a chicken-and-egg problem: both entities can only be inserted if the other one is inserted first.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved.

I think that's another far-reaching consequence of this design decision. In EF6, even with its crippled `AddOrUpdate`, at least it was possible to call `SaveChanges` twice to accommodate this scenario.

Considering that on top of all this, seeding isn't migration-friendly my stance on data seeding is: either don't support it (I wouldn't mind) or support it well.

Comment: A small correction. Adding explicit FK properties to the entity model is not strongly necessary. `HasData` accepts arbitrary objects, so anonymous types can be used to provide the required FK property values. This is mentioned in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data). Of course it's much more error prone than using strongly typed entity classes, but allows seeding entity models w/o explicit FK properties.

Comment: @Ivan Correct, forgot about that. I wrote this from a long-standing frustration about EF being so preoccupied with foreign key associations, so that carried me away a bit. Even with shadow properties it still stands, although it could be a viable work-around for OP. I think years ago they missed a vital turn when EF's architecture could still have been shaped into better support for independent association, or even IAs being the primary mode, and FKAs merely an escape route for exceptional cases. Ladislav Mrnka once had a great post on this topic which I can't find any more, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ModelBuilder to seed data :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData(
    new Post() { BlogId = 1, PostId = 1, Title = "First post", Content = "Test 1" });
```

Answer (score -2):

```
   protected override async void Seed(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.


        context.Test.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
                 new Test() { Id = 1, Name = "Test" }
        );
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
```

in PM  insert:
1. Enable-Migrations 
2. Add-migration Initial
3. Update-database

Answer (score -2):

if you don't like to use "ef core modelbuilder" or "ef core migrations", you can create default records in application layer. You don't need modelbuilder or migartions. Like this.

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
    SeedData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope().ServiceProvider);

       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }

    // your code...
}
```

SeedData.cs

```
internal class SeedData
{
    static AppDbContext _dataContext;

    internal static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _dataContext = (AppDbContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(AppDbContext));

        var ensureCreated = _dataContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        if (ensureCreated)
        {
            CreatePersonData();
            CreateGameData();
            CreateStudioData();

            try
            {
                _dataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CreatePersonData() { /* your code... */ }
    private static void CreateGameData() { /* your code... */ }
    private static void CreateStudioData() { /* your code... */ }
}
```

Comment: This is not recommended in .NET Core

Answer (score -2):

I would create an extension method to seed your data:

```
public static class DataContextExtensions
{
    public static void EnsureSeedDataForContext(this AppDbContext context)
    {

    // first, clear the database.  This ensures we can always start fresh. This is optional ! 
        context.Games.RemoveRange(context.Games);
        context.SaveChanges();

        // init seed data
        var games = new List<Games>()
        {
            new Games()
            {
                 Id = new Guid("25320c5e-f58a-4b1f-b63a-8ee07a840bdf"),
                 Name = "Stephen King",
                 Price= 14.99
                 Genre =  new Genre(),
                 Studio = new Studio(),
            }
        }

        //can seed other context data here

        context.Games.AddRange(games);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Then in your startup.cs file on the configure method you can call the extension method and then do your migrations commands:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, AppDBContext appDbContext)
 {
      appDbContext.EnsureSeedDataForContext();
      app.UseHttpCacheHeaders();
      app.UseMvc();
 }
```

To me its not complicated and easy to work with when it comes to stubbing data. But the above examples are great too ! Hope this helps.

Comment: Game and Studio has a circular dependency as mentioned.

Comment: Not recommended in EF Core.